# VBA SysCmd Compile error (Sub or Function not defined)

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to developing code for VBA, I am working on function that runs from an Excel document, the objective is to upload files to sharepoint passing the user credentials, when I compile it I error on SysCmd (Sub or Function not defined), please advice... thanks in advance.

The function is triggered from Excel,

```
Public Sub CopyToSharePoint()

On Error GoTo err_Copy

    Dim xmlhttp
Dim sharepointUrl
Dim sharepointFileName
Dim tsIn
Dim sBody
Dim LobjXML As Object
Dim UserName As String
Dim pw As String
Dim RetVal
Dim i As Integer
Dim TotFiles As Integer
Dim Start As Date, Finish As Date
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fldr As Object 'Folder
Dim f As Object 'File

Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("c:\vba2sharepoint\")

UserName = "mysharepointusername@domain.com" 
pw = "mysharepointpassword" 
sharepointUrl = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz-uat/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/a1docsuat/"

Set LobjXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

TotFiles = fldr.Files.Count

For Each f In fldr.Files

 sharepointFileName = sharepointUrl & f.Name

    Set tsIn = f.OpenAsTextStream
    sBody = tsIn.ReadAll
    tsIn.Close

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

    xmlhttp.Open "PUT", sharepointFileName, False, UserName, pw

    xmlhttp.Send sBody

  i = i + 1

  RetVal = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, "File " & i & " of " & TotFiles & " copied...")

Next f

   RetVal = SysCmd(acSysCmdClearStatus)

  Set LobjXML = Nothing

  Set fso = Nothing

err_Copy:

MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description

If Err <> 0 Then
  MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
  Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SysCmd` is an MS Access method ([Application.SysCmd Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214117%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), not an Excel method.

You want to set the status bar text directly as a string passed to an `Application.StatusBar` object.

```
 dim msg as string
 msg = "New Statusbar text"
 Application.StatusBar = msg
 Application.StatusBar = "other text"
```

Either of the last two lines will set the status bar text. To remove custom text, set it to `vbNullString`.

```
 Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
```

See this Excel property reference at [Application.StatusBar Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835916.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Jeeped, thanks for you help, that solved the compile error issue. I still have problems with my code,  it returns an alert window with the message number 0.

Comment: @JPAndino - It looks like you are falling into the `err_Copy:` label simply because it is the next place to go. Place an `Exit Sub` directly above `err_Copy:`. If you error, it will still go there due to the `On Error GoTo err_Copy` but it won't 'fall into' it just because it is the next step.

Comment: I commented out the lines regarding the error handling and I get; Run time error '-2147012890 (80072ee6)' Automation error.

Comment: Not really clear on what's happening here. Perhaps you could edit your original question with the updated code or start a new question with that same updated code, any error messages and the lines they originate from.

Comment: I just did, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104123/vba-code-run-time-error-2147012890-80072ee6-automation-error. Thanks! @Jeeped